# Yosemite Error With curl

Tags: macos, curl, libcurl, osx-yosemite

While attempting to get my new Yosemite machine up and running, I found this error while installing HomeBrew and MacPorts.

```
Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib Referenced from: 
/usr/local/bin/curl Reason: Incompatible library version: curl requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libcurl.4.dylib provides version 7.0.0
```

I tried various answer here and elsewhere but ultimately settled on the method left in the answers section.

Answer (score 3):

The error mentions that the curl files reside at:

```
/usr/local/bin/curl
```

But through some digging I discovered there was another version of curl located at

```
/usr/bin/curl
```

Since the version inside of /usr/local/bin/curl was producing the error, I decided to copy the files from /usr/bin/curl into /usr/local/bin/curl . That was it, everything works fine now.